# What's the difference between object in scalajs scope and *same* object in js.global scope?

Tags: javascript, scala, three.js, scala.js

I'm trying to write a simple example to render cube with THREEJS lib.

```
package three

import org.scalajs.dom

import scala.scalajs.js
import scala.scalajs.js.Dynamic._
import scala.scalajs.js.annotation.JSName

object THREE extends js.Object
{
  @JSName ("THREE.Scene")
  class Scene extends js.Object
  {
       def add(obj: js.Object) = ???
  }

  @JSName ("THREE.Vector3")
  class Vector3(var x:js.Number, var y:js.Number, var z:js.Number) extends js.Object

  @JSName ("THREE.PerspectiveCamera")
  class PerspectiveCamera(a:js.Number,b:js.Number,c:js.Number,d:js.Number) extends js.Object
  {
    var position:Vector3 = _
  }

  @JSName ("THREE.WebGLRenderer")
  class WebGLRenderer(params:js.Dynamic) extends js.Object
  {
    def render(scene:js.Object, camera:js.Object) = ???
  }

  @JSName ("THREE.WebGLRenderer")
  class SimpleWebGLRenderer() extends js.Object
  {
    def render(scene:js.Object, camera:js.Object) = ???
    var domElement : js.Dynamic = _
  }

  @JSName ("THREE.BoxGeometry")
  class BoxGeometry(a:js.Number,b:js.Number,c:js.Number) extends js.Object

  @JSName ("THREE.MeshBasicMaterial")
  class MeshBasicMaterial(params:js.Dynamic) extends js.Object

  @JSName ("THREE.MeshBasicMaterial")
  class SimpleMeshBasicMaterial() extends js.Object

  @JSName ("THREE.Mesh")
  class Mesh(geometry:js.Object, material:js.Object) extends js.Object

}


object ThreeExample
{
  def render() =
  {
    val scene = new THREE.Scene()
    val camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 1, 0.1, 1000);
    val renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(js.Dynamic.literal(
      canvas = global.document.getElementById("ThreeCanvas")
    ));
    val geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1);
    val material = new THREE.SimpleMeshBasicMaterial()
    camera.position.z = 2;
    val cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
```

Now the fun part. If I try to write

```
scene.add(cube);
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

I get

***ScalaJS.c.jl_ClassCastException {s$1: "[object Object] is not an instance of scala.runtime.Nothing$", e$1: null, stackTrace$1: null, stackdata: TypeError, constructor: function…}***

error. While if I try

```
global._scene = scene
global._cube = cube
global._camera = camera
global._renderer = renderer

global._scene.add(global._cube)
global._renderer.render(global._scene, global._camera);
```

everything renders correctly w/o errors.
I mean, what's the catch? 
Is there a difference between global._scene and scene or global._scene.add and scene.add ?

Comment: Quick fix: always specify the result type of methods of Scala.js objects, otherwise it's inferred as `Nothing` because of the `???`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment: there is basically no difference. The statically typed interface is only a typed facade to the same mechanisms that are used with the dynamically typed interface. However, because it is static, it adds checks to the values *returned* by the methods you call.

In your case, when calling `renderer.render()`, the compiler adds a check that the value returned by this JavaScript method actually conforms to the static result type of `WebGLRenderer.render()`. But what is this result type? It's `Nothing`! Why is that? Because the body of this method is `???`, which is of type `Nothing`, so scalac infers the method's result type as `Nothing`. The check then fails, because the value returned by `render` from JavaScript is not of type `Nothing` (obviously, since no value has that type), which causes the `ClassCastException`.

What you wanted is obviously not `Nothing`, but rather `Unit`. So all you have to do is to make explicit this result type with `: Unit` like this:

```
def render(scene:js.Object, camera:js.Object): Unit = ???
```

In general, you should *always* specify explicitly the result type of methods in facade types, because otherwise they're inferred as `Nothing`, which is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for full answer. Now I got your idea. For your first comment I didn't.